# How to redirect IP network to specific interface

Tags: networking, iptables, android-things

I'm developping an app for **Android Things DP4** on Rpi3.

I need my Rpi to send packets with destination IP in the network 10.110.2.0 with the interface wlan0 and packets with destination IP in the network 198.168.1.0 with eth0.
For the moment, when I send a packet, I always have the error message : `Network Unreachable`. It looks like I need to specify rules in iptables, but my only experience from iptables is from linux : and there are MANY more chains in Android.
I must select the interface when I use ping (`ping -I eth0 198.168.1.30`) otherwise, I have the error message `Network Unreachable`...

So : Does someone know how to route on an interface after checking the IP address ?

Answer (score 2):

Usually you should have a route for each interface similar to this, assuming your default gateway is `198.168.1.1` (your internet router?) and the ip address from the `wlan0` interface is `10.110.2.30`:

```
~$ sudo ip route
default via 198.168.1.1 dev eth0 proto static 
10.110.2.0/24 dev wlan0 proto kernel scope link src 10.110.2.30 
198.168.1.0/24 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 198.168.1.30
```

You can add (del) a route with:

```
~$ sudo ip route add 198.168.1.0/24 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 198.168.1.30
```

If your raspi should work as a router you also have to enable ip-forwarding in `/etc/sysctl.conf` and reboot.

```
~$ ~$ grep forward /etc/sysctl.conf 
# Uncomment the next line to enable packet forwarding for IPv4
#net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
# Uncomment the next line to enable packet forwarding for IPv6
#net.ipv6.conf.all.forwarding=1
```

or if you use `systemd-networkd` set `IPForward=yes` in your `/etc/systemd/network/iface.network` in section `[Network]`

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! The default keyword and the ip route works with 'add' before.  
Are we both under Android Things DP4 OS ?

Comment: @Maxime.D Oh sorry overseen that. I'm on Raspbian. But the principle should be the same.

Comment: I think so, but I can't find the syntax for Android Things, and I don't find any documentation about making ip routes on Android Things ...

Comment: As far as I know is Android a Linux derivate? Maybe you have to use the older version `~# route` instead of `~# ip route`. Is there a man page `~$ man ip` or ~$ man route` or something else? What about `ip help route` or `route --help` or so?

Comment: `ip route help` returns infos about how to use this tool but I doesn't help me since I don't understand it... I would like to show the output of `ip route help` but I don't have enough space in the comment section

Comment: `ip route help` works, that's good. Yes it's cryptic I know that. But we are near by. It should only be a syntax problem. Try from my example without `proto kernel`. google for examples.

Comment: My wlan0 IP@ : 192.168.2.98 is connected to a router at 192.168.2.69 wich is connected to 10.110.2.131.  My router works, I tried it. When I connect eth0 my Android Thing RPI doesn't know where to communicate... Well, I typed `ip route add 10.110.2.0/24 dev wlan0 scope link src 192.168.2.98`, had no display (success ?) but stil `Host unreachable` when I try to ping ..

Comment: I finally chose to use only eth0 interface. Under Android Things, it looks like : Android Things device CAN'T handle multiple interfaces and MUST have its IP address given by a DHCP service !

Answer (score 0):

So, I chose to send only on eth0, and not connecting the Wi-Fi.
The interface we want to use must have an IP address, BUT if you set it manually with `ifconfig wlan0/eth0 <yourIPaddress>` the Android Things device won't use it AT ALL : not event on the same network.

The Android Things device, needs a DHCP service available on the network.
And, it doesn't seems to be able to handle two interfaces at the same time : It will use the first interface connnected. If both Wi-Fi and Ethernet are available, the priority seems to be on the Wi-Fi.

One last thing : if you connect Wi-Fi after Ethernet (So you can't send data with the Wi-Fi as Android Things handles only one interface), you can receive on the Wi-Fi !

This interfaces limitation is not due to the Android API for Java, but by the OS itself, you can try as much as you want to specify the interface you want in your app, but is won't work as apps use the OS to work

Don't hesitate to add détails if you know more, this is only the result of my experiments